# Cargo install: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxcb

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rust, rust-cargo, lib

In Ubuntu22.04, it seemed to be lacking in libaries.

How could I solve it?

This is what the ld information is:

```
ld: mode elf_x86_64
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.a failed
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so failed
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64/libxcb.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64/libxcb.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libxcb.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libxcb.a failed
attempt to open /lib64/libxcb.so failed
attempt to open /lib64/libxcb.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libxcb.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libxcb.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libxcb.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libxcb.a failed
attempt to open /lib/libxcb.so failed
attempt to open /lib/libxcb.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libxcb.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libxcb.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libxcb.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libxcb.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libxcb.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libxcb.a failed
ld: cannot find -lxcb: No such file or directory
```

Comment: That means you need to install the development version of the xcb library. Probably [`libxcb1-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libxcb1-dev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a similar error message while trying to `cargo install jless` on Xubuntu 23.04, the info you may need is that `lxcb` is named `libxcb` in the package manager.

The error message I had:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxcb-xfixes: No such file or directory
```

What I did:

```
sudo apt install libxcb-xfixes0-dev
```

Hope this helps!